# setting IPv6 address for domain

Tags: domain, ipv6

I am quite new to the server business and I was wondering about a thing with the IPv6 addresses:

When I assign an IPv6 address for my domain as an AAAA record: Do I assign a /64 address or do I assign a complete single address out of the /64 that I got from my provider?

The thing is that I only got a /64 so I divided them somehow amongst my domains, but I get the impression that I am doing this wrong...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign a full address (/128) in a quad-A record. The /64 is a range of addresses for you to allocate from.

For example:

2604:4301:a:103/64 is my range, and I can use any address between 2604:4301:a:103:: (the `::` is shorthand for all-zeros) and 2604:4301:a:103:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question for, like, 100%. Thanks :) I will accept in 8 minutes, when I am allowed to accept. No more answers necessary here :)

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

How do you propose that you would assign a subnet to an AAAA record? :)

Per [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3596#section-2.1):

> The AAAA resource record type is a record specific to the Internet
> class that stores a single IPv6 address.